# Retrieve subset of many-to-many relationship in Rails/ActiveModel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, has-many-through, activemodel, ruby-on-rails-4

As an example, I have Doctors with many Appointments with Patients. I want to retrieve all Patients who are currently active in an Appointment:

```
class Doctor < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :patients, through: :appointments
end
```

And the Appointment model:

```
class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :patient_id, :began_at, :finished_at, :doctor_id
  belongs_to :patient
  belongs_to :doctor
  scope :active, where(finished_at: nil)
end
```

Now I can do something like `doctor.appointments.active` to get the active current appointments. But I want to get the patients easily of those appointments. Is there anyway to do something like `doctor.appointments.active.patients`? Or `doctor.patients.active` would make more sense.

Can I add the `active` scope to the `has_many :patients` line in the Doctor class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do

```
has_many :patients, :through => :appointments do
  def active
    where("appointments.finished_at is NULL")
  end
end
```

then:

```
doctor.patients.active
```

Comment: it strangely doesn't work. The SQL it outputs makes sense, but I get back an empty set even though the appoints.finished_at is in fact `nil`

Comment: the `finished_at` field is `nil` in Ruby. However, when I go to sqlite3, the field is empty.. I don't know what it is. If I do `sqlite> select * from appointments where finished_at=null;` I get nothing back. Even if I do `where finished_at=''` I get nothing back as well.

Comment: If I type the following in `rails console` I do get back the appointment, weird how `nil` works in Rails but not in sqlite3: `Appointment.where(finished_at: nil)`

Comment: Ok, I figured it out, apparently in SQL you can't check for NULL with `=`. You have to do the following: `appointments.finished_at is ?`

Comment: I updated the where statement to be pure SQL, since that is all we need.  Sorry about that.